# Get multiple values using lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a library with client documents with client account numbers, and another list with client information that contains the account number, household number, client name, etc. Some client account numbers have multiple household numbers associated with them. In my documents library, wherever there is a document with a specific account number I'd like to pull each household number into one (or more) fields, just to have them there for reference. Would a multi-value lookup field be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a household information in a different list as you mentioned and add a multi-value lookup column to the client documents library. This will create one to many relationship.

Comment: Is there a way for me to update the multi-value lookup with all instances of the account number in the other list using a workflow or some other automated way? Eg. if that account number has 3 household numbers associated with it, it shows me all 3 household numbers. Reason being, I have thousands of documents and it would take forever to update each one manually.

Comment: Do you want to update the Client Documents library in initial setup?

Comment: Basically, yeah. Once a document is in there, it won't be changed.